# Xcode how to upload an iOS app to TestFlight for External Testers

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

This is an action performed relatively rarely.

1. in Xcode the Product >> Archive menu does a build and brings up the Archive Manager
2. In the Archive manager there is a list of your attempts to Build this app.
3. Whatever I do it produces a list of errors and complains that the analysis file is too big (but it's all OK)

The question is How can I find out when it is ready to distribute to my external testers

Comment: there is quite big difference in how app is distributed to external testers and internal testers. For external it has to pass review process. Your question is a bit unclear to me. You decide if the app is ready to upload or not :)

Comment: Look into itunes connect. There is a tab containing information about the uploaded builds for a app.

Comment: You have to check the "builds" tab in iTunes Connect to see when it's ready. You also need your beta to be reviewed by Apple if you are distributing to external users.

Comment: Is there any positive indication that you have successfully uploaded it to the review process?  Otherwise I could have pressed the "wrong Button" and will wait for ever? It isn't in the Activity>>Builds page!

Comment: In the archive manager does "Upload to App Store..." succeed?